# macro to save a workbook with a different name

Tags: excel, vba

**background**

I have an excel workbook named scenarios.The excel workbook has several worksheets whose calculations are computed by an existing macro (call it macro1).

There are two worksheets of interest:"input" and "final"
The "input" worksheet is where I put my parameters while the "final" worksheet has the results of my current macro1 calculations.
Of interest is cell B3 in the "input" worksheet.Cells range A1:C1 in "input" worksheet contains values that I need cell B3 to reference(3 values i.e 100,200 & 300).

I need help with a new macro (call it macro2) to do the following;

**Required solution**

Change the value of cell  B3 by taking the values in turn from range A1:C1 in "input" worksheet (3 values i.e 100,200 & 300).

Change the value of cell B3 to 100(from cell A1),have my current macro1 do its calculations,then save the resulting workbook as scenario1.Secondly,again change value of cell B3 to 200(from cell B1),have my current macro1 do its calculations, then save the resulting workbook as scenario2.Thirdly,again change value of cell B3 to 300(from cell C1),have my current macro1 do its calculations then save the resulting workbook as scenario3.

Finally,I need the same new macro2 to open a new workbook and copy the "final" worksheet from each of scenario1,scenario2 & scenario3 workbooks.
Please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Scenarios()
    Const ADDR = "B3"
    Dim i As Integer, scen_val
    i = 1
    
    For Each scen_val In Array(100, 200, 300) ' place here all the scenario values
        With ThisWorkbook
            .Sheets("Scenario").Range(ADDR) = scen_val  ' make sure your workbook has a sheet named "Scenario"
            .SaveCopyAs .Path & "\Scenario" & i & ".xlsm" ' make sure your workbook has been saved. Other WB will be saved in the same directory
            i = i + 1
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This solution worked quite well.Now I have a modification to the question.